# Testing intervals in an absolute linear inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

My girlfriend is currently taking a math course and I'm giving her a bunch of help with her homework. She's working on linear inequalities right now, which are fairly simple for me. Her homework had a question in it that I was able to figure out the answers for using her notes, but I don't really understand why and I'm hoping someone here might be able to explain it to me. I'm paraphrasing the wording of the question a bit, but the parameters are the same.

The linear inequality $\lvert x\rvert < 27$ may or may not contain the intervals $(-\infty, A)$, $(A, B)$, and $(B, \infty)$ where $A < B$.

To answer the question, you have to find $A$, find $B$, and say whether or not each of the intervals is contained within the linear inequality.

The correct answers are: $A = -27$, $B = 27$, and No, Yes, No for the 3 intervals.

Now, I understand where the $-27$ and $27$ come from (it's the bounds of the linear inequality), but I don't understand why $A$ and $B$ equal those numbers. An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
I just want to clarify a little bit that I do understand that the interval notation of the inequality is $(-27, 27)$. My question is how to know to map that interval to $(A, B)$. In case it will help, my motivations behind this are to be able to understand more complex versions of this question. This one I can do in my head, but if there was a $y$ added to the mix or if the test intervals were perhaps something like $(A, B + A)$ (assuming that's even possible). I just want to be able to understand the question to the best of my ability so that I can identify similar questions in the future and apply the same knowledge to its solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know what the abosoute value means. The question is asking you which intervals contain solutions that satisfy |x|<27. Now, $|\pm\infty| = \infty>27$ so it cannot be a solution, therefore the solution intervals must be bounded. $|\pm27|=27 \nless 27$ so the interval cannot contain values $x>27$ or $x<-27$ since the absolute values of those x's will violate |x|<27. Therefore you are left with the open interval $(-27,27)$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about $|x|$ is as "the distance between $x$ and $0$." Consequently, we can think of the inequality $|x|<27$ as "$x$ is strictly within a distance of $27$ from $0$." This tells you that $-27<x<27,$ so that $x\in (-27,27).$ This is, of course, of the form $(A,B),$ where in particular $A=-27$ and $B=27$.

For all that, though, the question is awkwardly phrased. Saying that "the inequality contains [an interval]"...what could that mean? It appears that it intends to ask this:

> Which of the following could be component intervals of the solution set to the inequality $|x|<27$ (where $A<B$)?
>
> - $(-\infty,A)$
> - $(A,B)$
> - $(B,\infty)$

Comment: Yeah, this is all stuff that I got and understood. I guess my confusion comes from why isn't (A, B) instead (-26, 26) or (0, 1)? Or further to that, why isn't (A, B) something invalid, like (-100,100)? I'm really just missing how to make the jump from the x interval to (A, B).

Comment: Ah! I see. When I say *component intervals* of the solution set, I mean the largest intervals that are contained in the solution set. It's certainly true that $(-26,26)$ and $(0,1)$ are contained in the solution set of the given inequality, but the (only) component interval is $(-27,27).$ On the other hand, if the inequality were $|x|\ge 27,$ then the component intervals would be $(-\infty,-27]$ and $[27,\infty).$ Does that make sense? What was the original phrasing of the problem? It might be easier for me to answer if I knew that.

Comment: I'm at work right now, so I'll have to get back to you on that. I think that the component interval bit might be the missing piece. I'm going to do a bit of digging as well as re-reading the original question. Thanks. :)